# SQL GROUP BY as new columns

Tags: android, sql, sqlite, android-sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 to query a database of students, where only **students** table exists.
The columns that matter here are **governorate** and **grade**.

I want to see the percentage of students that got above 90% in each governorate so I wrote the following query:

```
SELECT governorate, CASE
                WHEN grade > 360 AND grade <= 410 THEN '90%'
                WHEN grade > 320 THEN '80%'
                WHEN grade > 280 THEN '70%'
                WHEN grade > 240 THEN '60%'
                WHEN grade > 200 THEN '50%'
                WHEN grade > 160 THEN '40%'
                WHEN grade > 120 THEN '30%'
                WHEN grade > 80 THEN '20%'
                WHEN grade > 40 THEN '10%'
                WHEN grade > 0 THEN '0%'
                WHEN grade == 0 THEN '0'
             END AS bucket, COUNT(*) AS number FROM students GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Now this only tells you the *number* of students in each bucket, not the *percentage* of the total governorate students.

And it creates ten rows for each governorate, what I want is to create a new column labeled **90-100** and ORDER BY that column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQLite, you can use a subquery:

```
SELECT governorate,
       (CASE WHEN grade > 360 AND grade <= 410 THEN '90%'
                WHEN grade > 320 THEN '80%'
                WHEN grade > 280 THEN '70%'
                WHEN grade > 240 THEN '60%'
                WHEN grade > 200 THEN '50%'
                WHEN grade > 160 THEN '40%'
                WHEN grade > 120 THEN '30%'
                WHEN grade > 80 THEN '20%'
                WHEN grade > 40 THEN '10%'
                WHEN grade > 0 THEN '0%'
                WHEN grade = 0 THEN '0'
             END) AS bucket,
        COUNT(*) AS number,
        COUNT(*) * 100.0 / c.cnt as percentage
FROM students s CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM students) c
GROUP BY 1, 2;
```

Comment: This does indeed tell me the percentage, but the buckets still create a new row. I want the row to contain **governorate | 90% | 80% | etc...** With the percentage of each bucket underneath each column.

Comment: @KhaledEmara Then add a [pivot](https://modern-sql.com/use-case/pivot) operation.